# If $B \in RE$ then $A \in RE$ - Reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, reductions, turing-recognizable

I know that if there is a Turing Reduction from $A$ to $B$, say $A \le_T B$, and $B \in R$ then $A \in R$.

I also know that Turing Reduction is for Decision, and not Recognition.

Is it possible to design a new type of reduction, such that if $B \in RE$ then $A \in RE$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: To my knowledge, many-one reduction does that.

Comment: Also RE contains languages, i.e., decision problems.

Comment: Can you further explain please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Mapping reduction is the reduction that can do that.

Mapping reduction is defined as A is many reducible to B if there is some computable((recursive))function say f such that
For all x, x belongs to A if and only if f(x) belongs to B. It can be proved that in many one reducability if B is r.e, then so is A.